# Django: how to give mp3 file correctly

Tags: python, django, http-headers, mp3

The problem is I can't change playing position by clicking on a timeline in google Chrome (it always plays from start to end)
If **Nginx gives** mp3 file to the client everything is **OK** and I can change playing position.

---

In my script I give mp3 this way:

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
wrapper = FileWrapper(file( 'mp3file.mp3' ))
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='audio/mpeg')
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize( 'mp3file.mp3' )
return response
```

The url is: `http://server/mp3/###.mp3`

So the whole file is given to the client, but still playing pos can't be changed. What is wrong?

PS:
Do not use any proprietary sh*t like mp3 - use ".ogg" format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the headers should handle additiona headers (like Accept-Ranges), and it should handle partial file requests

Doing this kind of things inside Django itself is a mess (I tried it some time ago), but then I ended up using Apache for serving files (this way you just don't waste resources)

You can consider using [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) for being able to serve files from your django view using apache, in this way for example:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='audio/mpeg')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
response['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path_to_file)
return response
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about user access? For example allow only registered and entered users to download files. Such things can be done only in scripts. Or I'm not right? (I understand that serving static files should be done by fast server, what to do in this situation?)

Comment: the code i posted above could be inside your django views, so it's up to you to decide wether send the file or redirect the user somewhere else if it is not registered. So yes, you can restrict the access to the files using mod_xsendfile.